# SetWindowPlacement doesn't seem to work correctly regarding the "rcNormalPosition" member

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on a Win32 C++ app.  I am trying to persist the bounds and maximized/minimized/normal state of the window.

In my window's `WM_DESTROY` handler, I'm getting the `WINDOWPLACEMENT` structure for the window and storing it in the registry.

In my window's `WM_CREATE` handler, I'm retrieving the previously saved `WINDOWPLACEMENT` structure and calling `SetWindowPlacement()` with it.  If the window wasn't maximized or minimized when the structure was saved, everything works as expected.

However, if the window was minimized or maximized, the window gets appears minimized or maximized as expected, but does not restore to the correct position.  If the window was maximized, then clicking the restore button keeps the window the same size.

Here are the declarations for the functions I've created to persist the structure:

```
[[nodiscard]] std::optional<WINDOWPLACEMENT> LoadMainWindowPlacement();
void SaveMainWindowPlacement(const WINDOWPLACEMENT& placement);
```

In these two functions, the `length` member has already been set.  For `SaveMainWindowPlacement()`, it's been set by the calling code.  For `LoadMainWindowPlacement()`, it's set within the function.

The `WM_DESTROY` handler:

```
case WM_DESTROY:
{
    WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = {};
    placement.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
    GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, &placement);
    SaveMainWindowPlacement(placement);
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The `WM_CREATE` handler:

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    auto placement = LoadMainWindowPlacement();
    
    if (placement.has_value())
    {
        SetWindowPlacement(hwnd, &placement.value());
    }
    else
    {
        const auto screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMAXIMIZED);
        const auto screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMAXIMIZED);
        RECT windowRect;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &windowRect);
        const auto windowWidth = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
        const auto windowHeight = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
        const auto x = (screenWidth - windowWidth) / 2;
        const auto y = (screenHeight - windowHeight) / 2;
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, nullptr, x, y, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE);
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The code that persists the windowPlacement structure:

```
HKEY hkSettings;
if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_SUB_PATH, 0, nullptr, 0, KEY_WRITE, nullptr, &hkSettings, nullptr) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    RegSetValueEx(hkSettings, L"MainWindowPlacement", 0, REG_BINARY, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&placement), sizeof(placement));
    RegCloseKey(hkSettings);
}
```

The code that retrieves the windowPlacement structure from storage:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = {};
HKEY hkSettings;
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_SUB_PATH, 0, KEY_READ, &hkSettings) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    DWORD dwType;
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(placement);
    if (RegQueryValueEx(hkSettings, L"MainWindowPlacement", 0, &dwType, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&placement), &dwSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (dwType == REG_BINARY && dwSize == sizeof(placement))
        {
            RegCloseKey(hkSettings);
            return placement;
        }
    }
    RegCloseKey(hkSettings);
}
```

Is there something I'm missing or doing incorrectly?

Comment: `ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);` You can use `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED` and `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED` depending on what state you want.

Comment: If the window identified by the hWnd parameter is maximized, the showCmd member is `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED`. If the window is minimized, showCmd is `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED`. Otherwise, it is `SW_SHOWNORMAL`.

If the information specified in `WINDOWPLACEMENT` would result in a window that is completely off the screen, the system will automatically adjust the coordinates so that the window is visible, taking into account changes in screen resolution and multiple monitor configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was persisting the `WINDOWLACEMENT` structure incorrectly.  I used GitHub Copilot to come up with the code that persists the structure, and it decided that persisting the entire structure in a registry value of type `REG_BINARY` was the way to do it.

After that didn't work, I modified the code to store each member of the structure in its own registry value of type `REG_DWORD` which worked as expected.

Here is the code that works:

```
void SettingsSaveMainWindowPlacement(const WINDOWPLACEMENT& placement)
{
    HKEY hkSettings;
    if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_SUB_PATH, 0, nullptr, 0, KEY_WRITE, nullptr, &hkSettings, nullptr) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        HKEY hkMainWindowPlacement;
        if (RegCreateKeyEx(hkSettings, REG_KEY_MAIN_WINDOW_PLACEMENT, 0, nullptr, 0, KEY_WRITE, nullptr, &hkMainWindowPlacement, nullptr) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            RegSetValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"length", 0, REG_DWORD, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&placement.length), sizeof(placement.length));
            RegSetValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"flags", 0, REG_DWORD, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&placement.flags), sizeof(placement.flags));
            RegSetValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"showCmd", 0, REG_DWORD, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&placement.showCmd), sizeof(placement.showCmd));
            RegSetValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"ptMinPosition.x", 0, REG_DWORD, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&placement.ptMinPosition.x), sizeof(placement.ptMinPosition.x));
            RegSetValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"ptMinPosition.y", 0, REG_DWORD, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&placement.ptMinPosition.y), sizeof(placement.ptMinPosition.y));
            RegSetValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"ptMaxPosition.x", 0, REG_DWORD, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&placement.ptMaxPosition.x), sizeof(placement.ptMaxPosition.x));
            RegSetValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"ptMaxPosition.y", 0, REG_DWORD, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&placement.ptMaxPosition.y), sizeof(placement.ptMaxPosition.y));
            RegSetValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"rcNormalPosition.left", 0, REG_DWORD, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&placement.rcNormalPosition.left), sizeof(placement.rcNormalPosition.left));
            RegSetValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"rcNormalPosition.top", 0, REG_DWORD, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&placement.rcNormalPosition.top), sizeof(placement.rcNormalPosition.top));
            RegSetValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"rcNormalPosition.right", 0, REG_DWORD, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&placement.rcNormalPosition.right), sizeof(placement.rcNormalPosition.right));
            RegSetValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"rcNormalPosition.bottom", 0, REG_DWORD, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&placement.rcNormalPosition.bottom), sizeof(placement.rcNormalPosition.bottom));
            RegCloseKey(hkMainWindowPlacement);
        }
        RegCloseKey(hkSettings);
    }
}

std::optional<WINDOWPLACEMENT> SettingsLoadMainWindowPlacement()
{
    WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = {};
    HKEY hkSettings;
    if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_SUB_PATH, 0, KEY_READ, &hkSettings) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        HKEY hkMainWindowPlacement;
        if (RegOpenKeyEx(hkSettings, REG_KEY_MAIN_WINDOW_PLACEMENT, 0, KEY_READ, &hkMainWindowPlacement) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            DWORD uintLength = sizeof(placement.length);
            DWORD longLength = sizeof(placement.rcNormalPosition.left);
            RegQueryValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"length", nullptr, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&placement.length), &uintLength);
            RegQueryValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"flags", nullptr, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&placement.flags), &uintLength);
            RegQueryValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"showCmd", nullptr, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&placement.showCmd), &uintLength);
            RegQueryValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"ptMinPosition.x", nullptr, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&placement.ptMinPosition.x), &longLength);
            RegQueryValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"ptMinPosition.y", nullptr, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&placement.ptMinPosition.y), &longLength);
            RegQueryValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"ptMaxPosition.x", nullptr, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&placement.ptMaxPosition.x), &longLength);
            RegQueryValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"ptMaxPosition.y", nullptr, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&placement.ptMaxPosition.y), &longLength);
            RegQueryValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"rcNormalPosition.left", nullptr, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&placement.rcNormalPosition.left), &longLength);
            RegQueryValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"rcNormalPosition.top", nullptr, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&placement.rcNormalPosition.top), &longLength);
            RegQueryValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"rcNormalPosition.right", nullptr, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&placement.rcNormalPosition.right), &longLength);
            RegQueryValueEx(hkMainWindowPlacement, L"rcNormalPosition.bottom", nullptr, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&placement.rcNormalPosition.bottom), &longLength);
            RegCloseKey(hkMainWindowPlacement);
            RegCloseKey(hkSettings);
            return placement;
        }
    }

    return std::nullopt;
}
```

Comment: So the issue is in code we cannot see. That doesn't make for a valuable Q&A. Please fix the question by adding the functions that are wrong.